# Нужно заменить каждую букву слова, которое находится в массиве на * JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, циклы, валидация

При нажатии на кнопку cenzor нужно заменить каждую букву слова, которое находится в массиве на "*". Не понимаю как нужно поставить условие.
То есть, в данном случае если мы вводим большой текст в textarea то при нажатии на кнопку cenzor слово "java" и "html" будут выглядеть так **** и ****.
И это все нужно сделать не используя регулярные выражения

```js
let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
let cenzor = document.getElementById('cenzor');

let badWordsArray = ['java', 'html'];

cenzor.addEventListener('click', function() {

  for (let i = 0; i < badWordsArray.length; i++) {
    if (textarea.value.includes(badWordsArray[i])) {
      console.log(true);

    } else {
      console.log(false);

    }
  }

})
```

```html
<textarea name="" placeholder="Write some text" id="textarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Cenzor" id="cenzor" class="btn btn-success">
```

Comment: textarea обязателен? через обычный input есть интересный юзкейс

Comment: @grime ну, желательно бы через textarea

Comment: а второе нажатие на цензор снова звездочки на слова меняет?

Comment: @grime не меняет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

заменяет на звездочки если badWords отдельное слово

```js
cenzor.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textarea.value = textarea.value.split(' ').map(word => badWordsArray.includes(word) ? '*'.repeat(word.length) : word).join(' ');
})
```

заменяет на звездочки даже если badWords в составе другого слова

```js
let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
let cenzor = document.getElementById('cenzor');

let badWordsArray = ['java', 'html'];

const replacer = word => {
  for (let i = 0; i < badWordsArray.length; i++) {
    const badWord = badWordsArray[i];
    if (word.includes(badWord)) {
      return replacer(word.replace(badWord, '*'.repeat(badWord.length)))
    }
  }
  return word;
}

cenzor.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textarea.value = textarea.value.split(' ').map(replacer).join(' ');
})
```

```html
<textarea name="" placeholder="Write some text" id="textarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Cenzor" id="cenzor" class="btn btn-success">
```

Comment: а что если это подстрока а не отдельное слово?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ жду когда уточнит)

Comment: не уточнил) но для будуших искателей ответов это на 95% актуально, плюсую авансом

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это отдельное слово)

Comment: @ТемныйМаг такая цензура не скушает словообразование =]